# How To Crop Multiple Images Separately

Tags: java, uri, crop, onactivityresult

I'm working on an app where user can upload three images at once but I'm having problem handling the onActivityResult() method. I can Crop one image using the codes below

```
private ImageView image1; 

// I need to crop three images this time. image1,  image2 and image3

private Uri imageUri; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

image1 = findViewById(R.id.image1);

image1.setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
CropImage.activity().start(MyActivity.this);
  }
 }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(
int requestCode,  int resultCode,  Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

imageUri = result.getUri();

image1.setImageURI(imageUri);
 }
}
```

My problem now is that I want to Crop three images but I don't know how to call each one of them in onActivityResult().